# Bewildered by 2GP Managed Package ancestor requirements

Tags: managed-package

I have the following package installed in a sandbox

```
Name                            Value
──────────────────────────────  ──────────────────
Name                            Base v2.2
Subscriber Package Version Id   04t1U000007Y7meQAC  <-- installed
Released                        true
Version                         2.2.0.1
Ancestor                        04t1U000007Y7l7QAC
Ancestor Version                2.0.0.6
```

I want to upgrade the sandbox to

```
    Name                            Value
──────────────────────────────  ──────────────────
Name                            Base v2.3
Subscriber Package Version Id   04t1U000007Y7nXQAS
Version                         2.3.0.1
Released                        true
Ancestor                        04t1U000007Y7l7QAC
Ancestor Version                2.0.0.6
```

When I attempt the install I get ...

```
Invalid Upgrade., Details: The currently installed version does not share a common ancestor with this version.
```

But both packages have the same ancestor!  I might be able to work around this by creating a version which has the installed version as the immediate ancestor and perhaps yet other version with the same code with version 2.0.0.6 as an ancestor to push into production.  Why should I need to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation is the same as the final example in the table in [Package Upgrades in Second-Generation Managed Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_upgrades.htm).

> Will this package upgrade succeed? No. To upgrade to 1.3.0.7, package version 1.2.0.3 must be the specified ancestor, or the specified ancestor must be a descendent of 1.2.0.3.

Your packages are *siblings* of one another, but 2.3.0.1 does not have 2.2.0.1 as an ancestor, so you cannot upgrade from 2.2.0.1 to 2.3.0.1. You could upgrade from 2.0.0.6 to *either* sibling, but you can't upgrade from either sibling to the other.

The text of the error message is confusing and doesn't reflect this specific situation.

Comment: Thank you so much!